# Redis 'COMMAND' command

Tags: redis, redis-commands

`redis-cli info commandstats` says `cmdstat_command:calls=4333329,usec=6417286195,usec_per_call=1480.91` for production server

This is about https://redis.io/commands/command

I see these COMMANDs in slowlog:

```
11) 1) (integer) 2012080
2) (integer) 1522069433
3) (integer) 10209
4) 1) "COMMAND"

15) 1) (integer) 2012076
2) (integer) 1522040830
3) (integer) 11295
4) 1) "COMMAND"

19) 1) (integer) 2012072
2) (integer) 1522022193
3) (integer) 10459
4) 1) "COMMAND"
```

Also I ran https://redis.io/commands/monitor for 10 seconds. Only two COMMANDSs are catched (out of 500k)

https://github.com/facebookarchive/redis-faina tool shows:

```
Slowest Calls
========================================
9441.25     "COMMAND"
7641.0      "COMMAND"
```

These COMMANDs were run from 127.0.0.1 and it is strange because all my clients have diffrerent ips

```
$ grep -i command monitor.txt
1522088442.990285 [0 127.0.0.1:48598] "COMMAND"
1522088448.073041 [0 127.0.0.1:48636] "COMMAND"
```

Can you explain who does these COMMANDs? Is it master/slave internals? Could not find the answer

Comment: Is this relating to the [`COMMAND` command](https://redis.io/commands/command)? Maybe one of your clients or adapters is hitting that really aggressively. You can always sniff these out with `MONITOR` to see who's doing it.

Comment: @tadman yes. all my clients are from different ips

Comment: I'd try and track down the ones that are running this repeatedly and find out why.

Comment: Depending on the client library, it is possible that it uses that command to inspect the server's capabilities upon connecting. If that is the case, you're either not using persistent connections or your network causes disconnects.